# https://url.com becomes https://12.34.56.67/ for no understood reason

Tags: redirect, iis-7

On IIS 7 one of our programmers is doing a Response.Redirect to a URL, and it comes back with the resolved IP ADDRESS in the address field.

UPDATE: this is happening BEFORE the response.redirect

1. Hard code a label as "https://url.com/whatever.aspx"
2. Display the page with that label
3. see "https://12.23.45.67/whatever.aspx"
   ... where 12.23.45.67 is the correct IP for "url.com"

This happens ONLY on the same server as url.com (different app) and ONLY for url.com

"https://test-url.com/whatever.aspx" DOES NOT get altered.

WTF?